# Confused about 'Function double getSales(float) already has a body' error

Tags: c++, function

does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Apparently I'm getting an because I'm setting up multiple function definitions with the same name but different parameters. But I don't understand how I would solve this programming question otherwise. The question states:

Write a program that determines which of a company’s four divisions (Northeast,
Southeast, Northwest, and Southwest) had the greatest sales for a quarter. It should
include the following two functions, which are called by main.

• double getSales() is passed the name of a division. It asks the user for a division’s
quarterly sales figure, validates the input, then returns it. It should be called once for
each division.

• void findHighest() is passed the four sales totals. It determines which is the largest
and prints the name of the high grossing division, along with its sales figure.

Input Validation: Do not accept dollar amounts less than $0.00.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getSales(float);
void findHighest(float, float, float, float);


int main()
{
    float Northeast;
    float Southeast;
    float Northwest;
    float Southwest;
    
    getSales(Northeast);
    getSales(Southeast);
    getSales(Northwest);
    getSales(Southwest);
    findHighest(Northeast, Southeast, Northwest, Southwest);
}

double getSales(float Northeast)
{
    cout << "Enter the quarter sales for the Northeast division: $";
    cin >> Northeast;
    while (Northeast < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter a positive number!";
        cin >> Northeast;
    }
    return Northeast;
}

double getSales(float Southeast)
{
    cout << "Enter the quarter sales for the Southeast division: $";
    cin >> Southeast;
    while (Southeast < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter a positive number!";
        cin >> Southeast;
    }
    return Southeast;
}

double getSales(float Northwest)
{
    cout << "Enter the quarter sales for the Northwest division: $";
    cin >> Northwest;
    while (Northwest < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter a positive number!";
        cin >> Northwest;
    }
    return Northwest;
}

double getSales(float Southwest)
{
    cout << "Enter the quarter sales for the Southwest division: $";
    cin >> Southwest;
    while (Southwest < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter a positive number!";
        cin >> Southwest;
    }
    return Southwest;
}

void findHighest(float Northeast, float Southeast, float Northwest, float Southwest)
{
    if (Northeast > Southeast && Northeast > Northwest && Northeast > Southwest)
    {
        cout << "Northeast is the highest grossing division!";
    }
    else if (Southeast > Northeast && Southeast > Northwest && Southeast > Southwest)
    {
        cout << "Southeast is the highest grossing division!";
    }
    else if (Northwest > Northeast && Northwest > Southeast && Northwest > Southwest)
    {
        cout << "Northwest is the highest grossing division!";
    }
    else if (Southwest > Northeast&& Southwest > Southeast&& Southwest > Northwest)
    {
        cout << "Southwest is the highest grossing division!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "There is a tie between 2 or more divisions for the highest grossing division!";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"is passed the name of a division"* - The variable name is not the name of the division. The name of anything would be a string. So you'd call it like `Northeast = getSales("Northeast");`

Comment: @ PhantomDiclonius You defined the function getSales declared like double getSales(float); four times. Pay attention to that according to the function description it should be declared either like double getSales( const char * ); or double getSales( const std::string & );

Comment: You can't discriminate functions by parameter names; only by types and quantity of parameters.

Comment: Any time you find that you are cutting/pasting code with only slight changes, take a step back and find a better design.

Comment: *I'm setting up multiple function definitions with the same name but different parameters* -- No you're not.  The parameter *type* is the same, `double`, and that's all that counts.  Then name could be "onefishtwofish", it wouldn't make a difference.  Also, you could have used arrays instead of 4 separate variables, thus reducing the code by at least half, if not more.

Comment: Also, use parameter names when declaring functions (prototypes).  Given `void findHighest(float, float, float, float)`, you can't tell the order.  From that declaration, is `NorthEast` the first parameter or the third?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have both `double getSales(float Southwest)` and `double getSales(float Northwest)`.

To your program, they are the same thing. If I'm going to write, in my main:

```
antartica = 3.0;
double money = getSales(antartica);
```

what is the compiler expected to do? Functions are meant to be called with whatever names the caller want and are distinguished by their name and parameter type. You should be able to get away with a single:

```
double getSales(const char* areaName)
{
    float area;
    cout << "Enter the quarter sales for the " << areaName << " division: $";
    cin >> area;
    while (area < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter a positive number!";
        cin >> area;
    }
    return area;
}

Northeast = getSales("Northeast");
Southeast = getSales("Southeast");
Northwest = getSales("Northwest");
Southwest = getSales("Southwest");
```

That will greatly reduce your amount of code, and make debugging and maintenance easier.

As you learn further about programming, you may come across the DRY principle:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I tried making my code more like yours but I get an error message on lines 11-14 saying: 'double getSales(float)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'float'
Here's lines 11-14:
    float Northeast = getSales("Northeast");
    float Southeast = getSales("Southeast");
    float Northwest = getSales("Northwest");
    float Southwest = getSales("Southwest");